# python-pptx not retaining text format when writing in a table

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Currently I am writing data into a table using python-pptx. The issue I am facing is that I am not able to retain the current Text format in the table. I am posting a sample Python code, please would someone help me.

Expected Outcome:
Cells should have text with the current formatting used in the template file, which is Segoe UI, size 8.

Outcome we are getting:
Cells are writing data with Calibri 18.

```
# get the first shape on the slide
shape = slide.shapes[3]

# get the table in the shape
table = shape.table

table.cell(1,1).text = '$ 14B'
```

I tried the above code, but I am unable to get the expected results.